# Dynamically create functions from hashtable with parameters in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, function, dynamic, new-item

### Question

Hi, I'd like to dynamically create functions from a hashtable in Powershell. But the created functions are supposed to be able to receive parameters.

The Code I have so far:

```
$functions = @{
    "wu" = "winget upgrade --include-unknown";
    "wui" = "winget upgrade -i -e";
    "wi" = "winget install -i";
    "wii" = "winget install -i -e";
    "ws" = "winget search"
}

foreach($funcName in $functions.PSBase.Keys){
    New-Item function:\ -Name $funcName -Value $([scriptblock]::Create($functions[$funcName])) | Out-Null
}
```

The problem is, that whatever I type behind the function is not considered a parameter:
[image]

Can you help me out?

### Answer

The finished result thanks to [@zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) & [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)

```
# Functions (separated for autocomplete)
$wg_functions = @{
    wu   = {winget upgrade @args}
    wui  = {winget upgrade -i -e @args}
    wuiu = {winget upgrade --include-unknown @args}
    wi   = {winget install -i @args}
    wii  = {winget install -i -e @args}
    ws   = {winget search @args}
}

$other_functions = @{
    dev = {Set-Location "W:/Projects/Development" @args}
    gtc = {git clone @args}
}

$functions = $wg_functions + $other_functions

foreach($funcKey in $functions.PSBase.Keys) {
    New-Item function:$funcKey -Value $functions.$funcKey | Out-Null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```sh
$functions = @{
    ws = { winget search $args }
    # ... and so on
}

foreach($funcName in $functions.PSBase.Keys){
    New-Item function:\ -Name $funcName -Value $functions.$funcName | Out-Null
}
```

- Define script blocks `{…}` directly in the hashtable, so you don't need to convert anything for the `New-Item` arguments.
- Use the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2) `$args` to forward arguments of the script block to the command. Note that for native commands, the `$args` array is unrolled automatically. For PowerShell commands you'd have to use *splatting* (`@args`).

Comment: Nicely done; if the placement of `$args` needs to be controlled or explicit parameter declarations are desired, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Append `@args` to your CLI calls, so that PowerShell passes all arguments passed to the function itself through:

```
foreach($funcName in $functions.PSBase.Keys){
  $null = New-Item function:$funcName -Value "$($functions[$funcName]) @args"
}
```

Note:

- `@arg` is the [splatted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) form of the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args). Given that you're calling *external programs*, `$args` would be sufficient in this case (either form results in the (stringified) array elements being passed as *individual arguments*), but if you were to call *PowerShell commands*, `@args` is required in order to pass *named* arguments through properly.
- As shown above, you can pass the function body as a *string* to [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) - it'll be converted to a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) automatically.
- The above assumes that all pass-through arguments go *at the end* of each of the CLI command lines that make up your functions. If you need more fine-grained control, use the technique shown in [zett42's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73345186/45375), which allows you to control for each CLI call where `@args` / `$args` goes or alternatively allows you to declare parameters *explicitly* with a `param(...)` block.